# how to save javascript console to the Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

i have a javacript code, i buy these code online. the code run the spinwheel game. and i want to save the result from spinwheel into database,
actually the js code already provide the result function but i didnt know how to save from the result function into mysql database.

here's the code:

```js
//Usage

//load your JSON (you could jQuery if you prefer)
function loadJSON(callback) {

  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', './wheel_data.php', true); 
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
      //Call the anonymous function (callback) passing in the response
      callback(xobj.responseText);
    }
  };
  xobj.send(null);
}

//your own function to capture the spin results
function myResult(e) {
  //e is the result object
    console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Win: ' + e.win + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);

    // if you have defined a userData object...
    if(e.userData){
      
      console.log('User defined score: ' + e.userData.score)

    }

  //if(e.spinCount == 3){
    //show the game progress when the spinCount is 3
    //console.log(e.target.getGameProgress());
    //restart it if you like
    //e.target.restart();
  //}  

}

//your own function to capture any errors
function myError(e) {
  //e is error object
  console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);

}

function myGameEnd(e) {
  //e is gameResultsArray
  console.log(e);
  TweenMax.delayedCall(5, function(){
    /*location.reload();*/
  })


}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    // Parse JSON string to an object
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
    //if you want to spin it using your own button, then create a reference and pass it in as spinTrigger
    var mySpinBtn = document.querySelector('.spinBtn');
    //create a new instance of Spin2Win Wheel and pass in the vars object
    var myWheel = new Spin2WinWheel();
    
    //WITH your own button
    myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError, spinTrigger:mySpinBtn});
    
    //WITHOUT your own button
    //myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError);
  });
}



//And finally call it
init();
```

can someone help me to give a tutorial or some reference for my problems?
thankyou.

Comment: convert js code to string using `JSON.stringify(jscode)` and save into database , and when you fetch that from database then user `JSON.parse(from database)` , for actual js code

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your using PHP at server end, if not Ajax will still work for you but you have to customize server script:

You need Ajax to share data from javascript to .php 
add jquery script by cdn - link: https://code.jquery.com/
After console.log statement use :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "sample.php", // replace your with .php file which will receive data 
        data: { 'spinCount':  e.spinCount, 'Win': e.win },

        success: function(result){

            console.log( result ); // Do what you want if data successfully trasfered.
        }
});




if( isset( $_POST['Win'] && $_POST['spinCount'] ) ){
    // store these in database
    $_POST['Win'];  
    $_POST['spinCount'];    
}
```